# How to use Amplify for implicit federated oauth w/ cognito *without* hosted UI

Tags: reactjs, amazon-web-services, single-sign-on, amazon-cognito, federated-identity

(Due to the confusion with what *is* amplify I'm borrowing the below from another post)

- I want to use the feature federation of a user pool **NOT** an identity pool
- I do **NOT**
  want to use this feature with the hosted UI.
- I do **NOT** want to use
  this feature with identity pool.
- I do **NOT** want to use this with
  the amplify CLI or amplify aws service

I am using `aws-amplify` https://www.npmjs.com/package/aws-amplify and the UI elements from `@aws-amplify/ui-react` and `@aws-amplify/ui-components`.

I am using `v1.2.26` of the `@aws-amplify/ui-react`

The webapp is a react app that runs on our own backend in elastic beanstalk.

We have a web application that uses cognito user pools and user/password to authenticate into our application and we would like to add the ability to use SSO starting off with `Google` and eventually implementing other `SAML` idp's.

Our ideal flow is for a user to click "Sign in with google" on our page and be immediately taken to a google login screen that once authenticated brings them into the application with a `refresh token` so that their user session can be persisted.

Currently getting the error `No Cognito Federated Identity pool provided`

Is there a way to do this or should we implement the auth flow manually? Amplify seems to be a mess unless you use it exactly as they want with the hosted UI and underlying amplify service.

```
// Amplify Configuration
import { Amplify } from 'aws-amplify';

  useEffect(() => {
    //Helpful for debugging
    Hub.listen(/.*/, info => console.debug(info));
  }, []);

  Amplify.configure({
    Auth: {
      region: pool.region,
      userPoolId: pool.id,
      userPoolWebClientId: pool.client,
      storage: window.sessionStorage,
      mandatorySignIn: false,
    },
    oauth: {
      domain: `myCognitoUserPoolTest.${pool.region}.amazoncognito.com`,
      //We don't have a sign-in or sign-out URL because its handled by Cognito right now
      redirectSignIn: 'http://localhost:3000',
      redirectSignOut: 'http://localhost:3000',
      // This is the default don't need it explicitly set
      // Setting this to "token" only returns a short-lived access token not a refresh token
      // responseType: 'code',
    },
  });

  return (<AmplifyAuthenticator
        federated={{
          googleClientId:'myGoogleClientID',
          //Put this in here to just to see 
          oauthConfig: {
            domain: '-domain-.auth.-region-.amazoncognito.com',
            //We don't have a sign-in or sign-out URL because its handled by Cognito right now
            redirectSignIn: 'http://localhost:3000',
            redirectSignOut: 'http://localhost:3000',
            scope: ['email', 'profile', 'openid'],
          },
        }}
      >
        <AmplifyGoogleButton
          slot="federated-buttons"
          clientId="myGoogleClientID"
          //Tried calling this explicitly, same result.
          onClick={() =>
            Auth.federatedSignIn({
              provider: CognitoHostedUIIdentityProvider.Google,
            }).then(res => alert(res))
          }
        />


      </AmplifyAuthenticator>);
```

Comment: Did you figure it out?

Comment: No we decided to go with an alternative authentication service